# PGAdmin4 fails to start every day in Mac: Error 'the application server could not be contacted'

Tags: postgresql, macos, pgadmin-4

I am running `pgAdmin4 version 3.0` on my Mac. Everyday when I try to start the app, I get this error:

> the application server could not be contacted

Per instruction in one of the threads I removed `.pgadmin/` from my root and `pgAdmin4 version 2.1` starts after that. I then install `version 3.0` and it works fine. However, the story repeats when I try to start the application the next time.